# how to create folder with my application name on Android Root

Tags: android, file, directory

how to create folder with my application name on android internal memory **not on the SDcard** and create on it files like whatsapp and viber any ideas ?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
File storagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/foldername");
storagePath.mkdirs();
```

don't forget to add permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Can ES File Explorer show the icon of my app in these folder?, I want that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example:

```
private MainActivity activity;
[...]
File fileDir = this.activity.getFilesDir();
```

I used this solution in an AsynTask. You can also use context.

getFilesDir()

> Returns the absolute path to the directory on the filesystem where files created with openFileOutput(String, int) are stored.
>
> Returns the path of the directory holding application files.